# Return only key value on AWS IOT rule to send date to DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm working on a project where I'm publishing some sensor data to a MQTT topic in AWS IOT. I have rule to insert that data to a DynamoDB table.

My published data looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "timestamp": 1591132839,
  "data": 71
}
```

Since I only need the value of the "data" key in my data column, my SQL query is:

`SELECT data FROM 'soil-moisture/#'`

I was expecting my values in my table to just be the value, e.g. 71, but instead I get:

`{ "data" : { "N" : "71" } }`

I've tried changing my query but I get these results:

`data.N` returns {}
`SELECT VALUE data...` returns some random String in data_raw column.

How do I just insert just the value of the "data" key into my table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This metadata is how DynamoDB stores items. You can't remove the data type as it is applied automatically.

The possible data types are documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html#Programming.LowLevelAPI.DataTypeDescriptors and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html.

From the first link:

> The low-level DynamoDB API protocol requires each attribute to be accompanied by a data type descriptor. Data type descriptors are tokens that tell DynamoDB how to interpret each attribute.

Some of the DynamoDB SDKs abstract these types away so you don't need to deal with them. e.g. the [Javascript DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html)

Comment: I might not have explained it correctly. This is what I get:
https://imgur.com/a/Fy5fmZc
The entries in the 'data' column are of map data type.